# Scala is not inferring the appropriate method

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

I have the following method

```
def show[E: Writes, T: Writes](block: RequestWithUser[AnyContent] => Either[E, T]): Action[AnyContent] = {
  withErr(block)
}
```

which I use like this from a controller:

```
def show(id: Long) = CrudAuthAction.show { request =>
  IdeaType.findByIdWithErr(id)
}
```

And I want the request method to be optional, so I defined another signature for the same method:

```
def show[E: Writes, T: Writes](block: => Either[E, T]): Action[AnyContent] = {
  withErr(request => block)
}
```

And it works fine, I can omit the request param

But when I try to do the same with this other method

```
def list[T: Writes](block: RequestWithUser[AnyContent] => T): Action[AnyContent] = {
  fromRequest(block)
}

def list[T: Writes](block: => T): Action[AnyContent] = {
  fromRequest(request => block)
}
```

When I want to use it like this:

```
def list = CrudAuthAction.list { request =>
  IdeaType.find(request.queryString)
}
```

it tells me that request is missing parameter type, and I have to specify it like this:

```
def list = CrudAuthAction.list { request: RequestWithUser[AnyContent] =>
```

I don't see what's different from the first case, but scala can't seem to infer the proper type of request...

The only difference I see is that in the first case, the block is returning an Either[E, T], but in the second case is returning just a generic T...

Comment: Needs minimal reproducible example. Depends on the definition of IdeaType.find, CrudAuthAction etc.

Comment: @themel: I don't think there's any requirement to post complete examples, especially if the problem is explained clearly and in detail, as it is here.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in the second example the compiler does not know which of the overloaded methods to pick, because T could well be a function type. Since `Either` is clearly not a function, it works in the first case.

To work around this issue, you could change the second method to

```
def list[T: Writes](block: => Foo[T]): Action[AnyContent] = {
  fromRequest(request => block.v)
}
```

With Foo defined like that:

```
case class Foo[T](val v:T)
```

Unfortunately, adding an implicit conversion to Foo breaks things again, unless you create an implicit conversion for each type in the `Writes` type class.

Comment: Let me see if I can follow you. You mean that in this case block: => T, can also match a function that takes one parameter, such as { request => ...}, so I should give more clues to the compiler...

Comment: no I meant that for all the compiler knows, T could be a function type.